# How do I allow the user to make a change to my site's appearance via php?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Let's say hypothetically that I have a Div that contains the background color 'red' and I would like the user to input into a separate input box to the side of the div what color he would like this box to be changed to. How would I go about allowing this type of functionality through php so that the color chosen (and not the default 'red') remains as the color once the user has left the webpage and another has logged on?

Basically how can I allow the users choice to be final so that users can see this afterwards?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to use a backend (server) for this.

Comment: Please improve our question: 1) What exactly is it you're trying to do? (*'stay on the website for good'* is not clear to me - do you want the item to be displayed again after the page reloaded?) 2) What have you tried so far for a solution, and why/how is it not working?

Comment: Sorry, my explanation is pretty terrible. I want to user to be able to add a div that contains text to a page on my website and for the div to actually be inserted into the html coding within another div so that the item added will stay there once the page has been reloaded. I am basically trying to create a back-end aspect within a news page on my website for an admin to be able to add news items at free will. Sorry for the horrid explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it on a client side. The HTML code should be generated on a server side and along with addition to DOM, AJAX call should be made to server-side script to include new elements in subsequent generations.

And you should also provide some sort of authorisation, or else your website will be full of Viagra and Forex links in no time...

Comment: So I wouldn't be able to create a back-end for my webpage with append?
What exactly is Ajax?

Comment: AJAX is a way to call server-side scripts asynchronously. Google it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the number of appended items back to the server and the server has to store that number in a database. Then, the next time the page is requested, the server can either render them or it can send the information to the client and the client can render it.